# Screech on startup (manual)

Tags: honda, starting, transmission, manual-transmission, accord

I have a 2008 Honda Accord K24Z3 with the 5-Speed Manual (178k miles), and I’ve got actually two questions/problems.

First; When I start up my car clutch+key turn, if I keep my foot on the clutch even a split second after engine turns over it makes a horrible screeching sound, I have found a couple possibilities online but it only happens on startup, it’s definitely not the engine, FYI it’s got 178k miles on it, I’m also going to swap out the transmission fluid with new Genuine Honda MTF, to see.

Second problem; my actual shifter doesn’t want to go into gear unless I bang my hand on it into first, it’s now also been making a loud metallic grinding noise when it actually engages the gears (foot completely on clutch too), I have driven it recently and it shifts perfectly fine and on time when actually driving, I’m also a bit gentle on the shifts too, just so it doesn’t wear faster.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks guys and gals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristics you describe point to a failed throw-out bearing. Between the clutch pedal and the clutch release mechanism is a bearing which transfers your foot pressure to the mechanism. When the clutch pedal is pushed, the bearing contacts a suitable surface that is (at start) not rotating, but when the engine operates, it begins to rotate.

The shifting aspect is consistent as well. If the bearing is damaged, you will be unable to release the pressure plate sufficiently enough to disengage the engine from the transmission, making it fairly difficult to engage a gear.

You may wish to engage first gear prior to starting the engine, but expect some engine power to be transferred to the wheels in so doing. Your foot brake or hand brake should be sufficient to keep the vehicle from moving.

As you may expect, this is a critical point of failure and should be repaired soonest.

From [another online forum](https://www.mustangevolution.com/threads/throw-out-bearing-question.295558/), this image may be of value:

[image: clutch and throw out bearing diagram]

Comment: @NewbieDubbie This answer is spot-on correct, but just to be certain that inadequate movement of the slave cylinder is not contributing to the problem, check to make sure your clutch fluid reservoir is not empty. You'll find it next to your brake fluid reservoir.

Comment: You guys rock! I had a feeling that the throw-out bearing could be an issue, thanks for confirming it based on the symptoms, I'll definitely check the clutch fluid too, I've been hesitant on buying new MTF (not common near me) as I do believe the transmission may have never been properly maintained, as well as being a flooded-remanafactured title car. You all have a good day!!!  